# Executing python script without being connected to server

Tags: python, linux

I need to execute python script on remote server (access through puTTY), but I don't have a stable Internet connection, and every time I execute the script I get problems after several minutes due to my Internet getting disconnected.

How do I remotely execute the script without being connected to server? 
(e.g. I connect to server, run script, and can logout while executing)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **Linux Screen**, it opens a background terminal and keeps a shell active even through network disruptions.

Open the screen typing in your terminal `$ screen` and execute there your script, even if you lose connection it won't kill the process.

[Here](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) you will find a well explained *How to* for this program. I use it for my regular day working on remote.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
nohup your_script >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

program will be running in background